# My system is sending spam, where to start fixing it?

Tags: ubuntu, spam, email

One of my smaller webservers appears to be sending out spam. It is a Ubuntu 8.04 system with Plesk as a configutation interface and qmail as the mailserver.

How to I go about identifying the spam-source? The server itself is a fresh install and it "started spamming" as soon as I transfered domains, data and databases from the old server (which didn't spam). The SMTP server definately needs secure authentication (it is not an open relay). I also checked for rootkits using rkhunter and chkrootkit while the servers filesystem was mounted readonly from another machine and found none.

I'm out of ideas. Hope anyone has some pointers.

Answer (score 3):

It's definitely being abused?  First of all, disconnect it from the Web, and secure the logs.  The source of the spam is either a) a local process that's been installed / compromised (like you say), b) or a bot somewhere using your server.  In either case, the logs will tell you where to look next.  I'd be worried either way, as this could be the thin end of the wedge.

Comment: (1) Check your webserver logs for activity which would suggest abuse of a script which sends mail (address the script directly if this is confirmed), (2) check your SSH logs to determine whether a user account has been compromised (may also want to proceed to #3 even if this is confirmed), (3) if you've exhausted likely culprits and your logs are inconclusive, consider your system compromised and re-image + restore from backups *and* update installed software *before* restoring the server to production.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that one or more web page is infected/compromised.

You should be looking at your apache logs. You can give it a try and scan the webserver root directories with clamav (it has patterns to find php "mailer kits" or other nasty things).

Answer (score 0):

You have to differentiate 3 scenarios:

1. A remote process is exploiting a web site to send mails directly. Look for vulnerable PHP code (not necessarily, but probable). The webserver logs will tell you.
2. A local account has been cracked, and a local process is sending the spam.
3. Additionally to 2, you box has been rooted.

Don't do forensic on the live system, take the machine off the net, look at the logs. When not abolutely sure where the problem is, assume 3. (nuke the box, reinstall, audit the web code, permit only key authentication)

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is vulnerable PHP code somewhere. If I can't find it I will definately reinstall and rebuild. The only services running besides mail, are Apache and SSH. The latter is only accessible by 3 users and only by key-authentication. I'll investigate further, thanks to everyone for the ideas on where to look.